# Use nested transformers in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

In my Laravel 5 app, I'm implementing Transformers and Fractal.
I've got in my example two different models: `User` and `UserLogin`. Every User can have multiple UserLogins (I've already added a one-to-many relationship between them). Now I want to "clean" my response, which returns an User with his UserLogins. So I've created two transformers, and I thought that I should call a transformer inside the other one inside his return, like here:

```
"UserLogins"=> Fractal::collection($user->userLogins, new UserLoginTransformer).......
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work and the error is that it doesn't find fractal library (which is correctly imported).

What could be the problem?

Comment: Hum... Laravel 5 does not use global namespacing anymore, did you make the "use ..." statement for your Fractal library ?

Comment: Yes, in my transformer is automatically added. "use League\Fractal;"

Comment: Can you post the error ?

Comment: FatalErrorException in UserTransformer.php line 37:
Class 'League\Fractal' not found

Comment: try a to do a "composer dumpautoload", maybe your classmap has to be rewrote by composer.

Comment: I've already done it. and nothing changed.

Comment: There could be a lot of reasn why Fractal lib is not found. Maybe try to run a composer install, or composer itself is out of date, run "composer selfupdate" then composer install, maybe it could fix the prob

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78871/discussion-between-bellots-and-chainlist).

Comment: Looks like you're using the spatie laravel fractal library perhaps? have you registered the facade in your config/app.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution.
Fractal class does not exists, I cannot make simplier than that.
And you weren't correctly  using the library.

So, the solution :

```
use \League\Fractal\Manager;
use \League\Fractal\Resource\Collection as FractalCollection;

$fractal = new Manager();
$resource = new FractalCollection($user->userLogins, new UserLoginTransformer);

return $fractal->createData($resource)->toArray();
```

Comment: If you want to remove "data" key in response, you can return current($fractal->createData($resource)->toArray());